# $f(tz)\rightarrow \infty$ as $t\rightarrow \infty$ when $f$ is convex

Tags: convex-analysis

Suppose $f:\mathbb R ^n \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is convex and not constant. How can I show that $f(tz)\rightarrow \infty$ as $t\rightarrow \infty$ for some $z\in \mathbb R ^n$?

This seems very intuitive because $f$ is defined on the entire space, but I just could not give any rigorous proof. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Choose some $z_0 \in \Bbb R^n$ with $f(z_0) \ne f(0)$. Then
$$
 h: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R , h(t) = f(tz_0)
$$
is convex with $h(1) \ne h(0)$.

For $t > 1$ and for $t < 0$ the graph of $h$ is above 
the line joining $(0, h(0))$ and $(1, h(1))$:
$$ \tag{1}
 h(t) \ge h(0) + t \bigl (h(1) -h(0) \bigr ) \, 
$$
therefore
$$
 \lim_{t \to \infty} h(t) = \infty \text{ or } \lim_{t \to -\infty} h(t) = \infty \, .
$$
It follows that $
 \lim_{t \to \infty} f(tz) = \infty $
holds for $z = z_0$ or for $z = -z_0$.

---

*Details* for $(1)$: A convex function $h$ satisfies
$$ \tag{2}
 h(x) \le \frac{x_2-x}{x_2-x_1} h(x_1) + \frac{x-x_1}{x_2-x_1} h(x_2)
$$
for $x_1 < x < x_2$, i.e. the graph of $h$ lies below the secant
joining $(x_1, h(x_1))$ and $(x_2, h(x_2))$.

Now if $x_1 < x_2 < x$ then $(2)$ inequality holds with $x$ and $x_2$
exchanged:
$$
 h(x_2) \le \frac{x-x_2}{x-x_1} h(x_1) + \frac{x_2-x_1}{x-x_1} h(x)
$$
and a simple rearrangement gives
$$ \tag{3}
 h(x) \ge \frac{x_2-x}{x_2-x_1} h(x_1) + \frac{x-x_1}{x_2-x_1} h(x_2) \, ,
$$
i.e. $(2)$ holds with the reversed inequality sign.
In the same way we can derive $(3)$ in the case $x < x_1 < x_2$.

Therefore the graph of $h$ lies above the line
joining $(x_1, h(x_1))$ and $(x_2, h(x_2))$ if  $x$ is outside
of the interval $[x_1, x_2]$.

Comment: How can you show that $h(t)\ge h(0)+t(h(1)-h(0))$? I tried to use the gradient inequality or the monoticity of the gradient, but it didn't work (and $h$ is not necessarily differentiable).

Comment: @MasterJ: I have added more details. Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: I'm sure this technique will come in handy in the future. Thanks.